# Running ZooInspector on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, apache-zookeeper

Freshly installed package of zookeeper also provides zooinspector program to view and edit nodes. Upon execution the latter silently crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Edit /usr/bin/zooinspector shell script to include the following jars:
   CLASSPATH=/usr/share/java/slf4j-simple.jar:/usr/share/java/log4j-1.2.jar:/usr/share/java/slf4j-api.jar:/usr/share/java/zookeeper.jar:/usr/share/zookeeper/zooinspector/zookeeper-ZooInspector.jar
2. Remove comments from /usr/share/zookeeper/zooinspector/config/defaultNodeVeiwers.cfg

Comment: It works! Just wanted to share. The best is to notify the maintainer as well.